# Which .jar file i need to add to remove errors from thease line in netbeans

Tags: java, apache, netbeans

Which .jar file i need to add to remove errors from thease line in netbeans.
error lines are

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.CookieStore;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.ClientContext;
import org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCookieStore;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
```

AND from where to download that .jar file?
thanks in advance.

Comment: what are the errors?

Comment: Errors are package<package name> doesnot exist.ex:package org.apache.http does not exist

Comment: Did you already try to [search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=org.apache.http) about them?

Comment: this kind of errors for each line.I dont know which jar file i  need.

Comment: You must add server runtimes which will contain j2ee.jar

Comment: can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

You need [apache HTTP client](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/project-reports.html). Take a look on linked site and find download.

Alternatively if you want to use one of popular build tools that manage your dependencies (e.g. maven or gradle) add http client to dependencies.

Comment: Ive downloaded thatfrom http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi and tried by adding all 10 jar files from the lib folder but nothing happened.

Comment: Classes that you need are in httpcore-4.4.3.jar. I am not familiar with netbeans but can assume that some kind of refresh or rebuild should solve your problem.